# Chrome webRequest API - Filtering out extension queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write an extension that repeats all queries made to a domain. The extension has two main functions

```
chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener
```

adds a function that stores the header values of the outgoing request. When the response is received, the function in

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener
```

repeats the request with Ajax. The problem is that this second request is caught by the listeners as well, causing it to loop. How do I filter this out?

Answer (score 0):

You could store a temporary hash of the headers/url (or just one header) when you repeat the request. Then, if you see the same hash again, skip it.

If the headers/url are not unique then if you are sending data you could use that.